# Validation Error in Django

Tags: python, django

i was trying to modify the UserRegistationFrom in django to make each Email address uniqe

I am a kinda noob in django. So by following tutorials and stuakoverflow question i wrote this for checking if email exist

by the way, i wrote everything in views for testing

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

class Signup(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(email=email)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return email
        raise forms.ValidationError("You have forgotten about Fred!")



def index(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        signup = Signup(request.POST)

        if signup.is_valid():
            return HttpResponse("All is well")
        else:
            return render(request,'website/index.html',{'form':Signup})

    return render(request,'website/index.html',{'form':Signup()})

def private(request):
    return HttpResponse("Ok")
```

And,
I am getting this error

```
ValidationError at /
[u'Error']
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 1.5.4
Exception Type: ValidationError
Exception Value:    
[u'Error']
```

Why i am having this error? And how to fix it?

Comment: You'll have to post your view code.

Comment: Question edited, Submitted the full view code as you told to

Comment: where is your `url.py` code ?

Comment: Hmm, that code looks fine. Strange. Where are you seeing the error? Do you have DEBUG set to True?

Comment: yes, my debug set to true.
Does urls.py really matters? well here is it
`from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'website.views.index', name='index'),
    url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
 url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey, i have fixed the bug :)
The problem was with
generating view

So the correct code it

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

class Signup(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data['email']

        try:
            u = User.objects.get(email=email)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return email

        raise forms.ValidationError("Error")




def index(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        signup = Signup(request.POST)

        if signup.is_valid():
            return HttpResponse("All is well")
        else:
            return render(request,'website/index.html',{'form':signup})

    return render(request,'website/index.html',{'form':Signup()})
```

**Thanks who tried to help me**